# iOS whats the best way of converting a float entered as string to a long

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I need to take a string from a UITextEdit that is a very large float value and convert it to a long so I can use it in calculations. I have tried using double's but they don't go large enough so I was hoping to turn the string into a long. The value entered will always have only 2 decimals.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Why not directly float to long??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example for converting string to long long int, and long long int to string;

```
// Converting string to long long int
NSString *text = @"12345678998765";
long long int num = [text longLongValue];

// Converting back to string
NSString *backToString = [@(num) stringValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSString method `longLongValue` to convert `string` to `long`

```
NSString *text = @"Your long number string";
long longNum = (long) [ text longLongValue];
NSLog(@"num = %ld", num);

or 

NSNumberFormatter * numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *num = [numFormatter numberFromString:text];
NSLog(@"long Number: %llu", [num longLongValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the number can only have up to 2 decimals, you can store in long a value that is equal to 100 * your number. If the number ALWAYS has 2 decimals (even when they are both 0), then you could do something like:

```
NSString *text = @"934968.34";
text = [text stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
long long number = [text longLongValue];
```

You can also add some code for cases where there is only 1 decimal (when, this case is detected, there should be number = number * 10 at the end) or none (in this case, number = number * 100)